# Covariance of transformed random variable

Tags: statistics

So I have the covariance $\mathsf{cov}(x_0,x_1)$ and I know $m_b=−2.5\log_{10}(x_0)+$constant, then how do I calculate $\mathsf{cov}(m_b,x_1)$

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/covariance-of-transformed-random-variables) but I guess it isn't useful here since it is transformation of both the variables.

Also i tried this
$\begin{align}\mathsf{cov}(m_b,x_1) &= \langle\Delta m_b , \Delta x_1 \rangle \\
& = d m_b , d x_1  \\
&= -2.5 /x_0 \, dx_0 , dx_1 \\
&= -2.5 /x_0  \mathsf{cov}(x_0,x_1) \end{align}$

but I am not so sure sure about this method

Comment: Well, the covariance should not be a function of a random variable, so *whatever* you are doing with the last method is not giving a valid result.

Comment: If all you know is $\mathsf{cov}(x_0,x_1)$ then I do not see how you can find $\mathsf{cov}(m_b,x_1)$.  Try a simple example such as $x_0=x_1$ being $1$ or $2$ with equal probability to get  $\mathsf{cov}(x_0,x_1)=0.25$ and $\mathsf{cov}(m_b,x_1)\approx -0.188$.  Then try $x_0=x_1$ being $11$ or $12$ with equal probability to get  $\mathsf{cov}(x_0,x_1)=0.25$ and $\mathsf{cov}(m_b,x_1)\approx -0.024$.